# Network Unreachable when cloning Github Repository?

Tags: networking, github, ssh

When I try to clone my repository on my OVH server, I get the following message:
`github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Network is unreachable`
How could I solve this? I am using Windows 7, it is a shared network, I do it in SSH.

The following conversations seems quite helpful but it is in french ([this](http://forum.ovh.com/archive/index.php/t-69339.html) and [this](http://forum.ovh.com/showthread.php?t=71543)).

Comment: what kind of server? shared or dedicated? do you do it in SSH?

Comment: @CharlesB thanks, it is a shared network, I do it in SSH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was easy: the files were in C:\WAMP\APPS